# How to use 2 lists to create a 3rd list using identifiers

Tags: excel, indexing, filter, excel-formula, match

I'm reaching out to see if there is a formula to have an array output from 2 different arrays using similar identifiers.

Anyone have any suggestions?

*provided array 1*

| ID | Account |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| A | 101 |
| A | 102 |
| B | 105 |

*provided array 2*

| User | ID |
| --- | --- |
| U1 | A |
| U1 | B |
| U2 | A |

*desired array 3 output*

| User | Account |
| --- | --- |
| U1 | 100 |
| U1 | 101 |
| U1 | 102 |
| U1 | 105 |
| U2 | 100 |
| U2 | 101 |
| U2 | 102 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va52u.png)

I've tried using helper columns and various filter methods. I'm able to get partly there but unable to generate an output like "Array 3".

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a PowerQuery question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Power Query

- Format your two arrays as Tables

  - I named them `Array1` and `Array2`.
- Select `Array1`
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
//change table names in code below to reflect the actual names in your workbook

let

//Read in first table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Array1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Account", Int64.Type}}),

//Read in second table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Array2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"User", type text}, {"ID", type text}}),

//Join the two tables
    #"Joined Tables" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type","ID",#"Changed Type2","ID","Joined", JoinKind.FullOuter),

//Expand the user column
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Joined Tables", "Joined", {"User"}, {"User"}),

//Remove the unneeded ID column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Joined",{"ID"}),

//Place columns in desired order for output
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"User", "Account"}),

//Sort the results
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"User", Order.Ascending}, {"Account", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Power Query did the trick!

I was able use provided code to generate the 1000+ assignments. Thank you so much for your help.

I'm not too familiar with Power Query and this sparked my interest to dive into it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Might be there is **more easy way** of doing this or in a **more eloquent** way, however you can ***try*** this as well using functions viz.

<kbd>LET( )</kbd> <kbd>TAKE( )</kbd> <kbd>DROP( )</kbd> <kbd>REDUCE( )</kbd> <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> <kbd>VSTACK( )</kbd> <kbd>TOROW( )</kbd> <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd>

<kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd> <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G1`

---

```
=LET(
       a,A2#,
       b,D2#,
       c,TAKE(a,,1),
       d,TAKE(a,,-1),
       e,TAKE(b,,1),
       f,TAKE(b,,-1),
       g,DROP(REDUCE("",f,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TOROW(FILTER(d,c=y))))),1),
       h,TOCOL(e&"-"&g,3),
       i,TEXTBEFORE(h,"-"),
       j,TEXTAFTER(h,"-"),
       VSTACK({"User","Account"},HSTACK(i,j)))
```

---

Note that as per your OP provided array one used in cell `A2`

```
={"A","100";"A","101";"A","102";"B","105"}
```

And provided array two used in cell `D2`

```
={"U1","A";"U1","B";"U2","A"}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% about the logic to generate the output based on the information provided in the question, but if this is what I think you can use the following. This solution doesn't require a [Lambda Helper Function](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648) which is usually less efficient:

```
=LET(AB,A2:B5, DE,D2:E4, A,TAKE(AB,,1), B,TAKE(AB,,-1),
 D,TAKE(DE,,1), E,TAKE(DE,,-1), x,IF(A=TOROW(E),B,NA()),
 ac,TOCOL(x,2,1), user,TOCOL(IF(x=B,TOROW(D),NA()),2,1),
 VSTACK({"User","Account"},HSTACK(user, ac)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We have two input ranges: `AB`, `DE` (the names refers to the column letters of the ranges), the rest of the names are deduced from them using `TAKE` function to extract the specific column.

The name `x` is an `mxn` array where `m` is the numbers of rows of `A` and `n` is the number of rows of `E`, where the element `i,j` represents the comparison of `Ai = Ej`, so it returns the corresponding `B` value, if they are equal otherwise `NA`(obviously it assumes `NA` is not a valid account number). We use `NA` later by `TOCOL` to remove such values. Here the output of `x`:

```
100  #N/A   100
101  #N/A   101
102  #N/A   102
#N/A 105    #N/A
```

**Note**: If we are able to concatenate by columns the previous matrix in a single column, then remove the `NA` values, this is the output we are looking for the accounts.

The name `ac` (accounts) uses `TOCOL` to concatenate by columns (`1` in the third input argument) the `x` matrix, removing the `NA` values (`2` in the second input argument).

For `user` we apply a similar logic using the `D` name as a single row via `TOROW`. It ensures the comparison is by columns of a given row. The last step is to use `VSTACK` to add the header to the expected output: `HSTACK(user, ac)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Create List From 2 Lists

[image]

```
=LET(fData,A2:B5,sData,D2:E4,fiCol,1,faCol,2,suCol,1,siCol,2,
    fi,INDEX(fData,,fiCol),fa,INDEX(fData,,faCol),
    su,INDEX(sData,,suCol),si,INDEX(sData,,siCol),
    u,UNIQUE(su),
DROP(REDUCE("",u,LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
    f,FILTER(fa,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(fi,FILTER(si,su=r))),""),
VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(INDEX(r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,,0)),f))))),1))
```